# Would it be possible to get married in church and in a mosque if I am Catholic and my girlfriend is Muslim? (have two weddings)

Tags: catholicism, marriage, love

Would it be an invalid marriage or is there a possibility that we can both show and make our marriage legal before God?

Comment: Your religions teach different Gods, they teach that the other person is destined for hell. If both of you truly believe in your religions, do you really think you should get married?

Comment: @curiousdannii What do you mean? For some reason do you believe that Islam condemns all non-Muslims to hell? You don't know anything about Islam, please, read before.

Comment: Well Catholics at least teach that. And doesn't Islam teach that worshipping Jesus as the divine Son of God is a [shirk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirk_(Islam)), a sin that will not be forgiven if someone dies without repenting of it?